# Finding number of occurence of a given number in an array

Tags: c++

I'm testing a recursive function that returns the number of occurrence of a given number in an array. I get an unexpected result when I run the code.

```
#include <iostream.h>

int Occurence(int A[], int size, int n)
{
    static int occur=0;
    if(size == 0)
    {
        int occur2 = (int) occur;
        return occur2;
    }

    else
    {
        if ( n == A[size-1])
            occur++;
        Occurence(A, size-1, n);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int A[] = {1,3,2,5,1,2, 3, 7,7, 8,8, 4, 6, 9,9, 0};
    int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);

    int n;
    cout<< "Enter Number to Find : ";
    cin >>n;

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Number of Occurence of "<< n << " is :"<< Occurence(A, size, n)<<endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: "Finding number of occurence of a given number in an array" --> [std::count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). "`int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);`" --> [const auto size = `std::size`(A);](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Comment: Your else branch doesn't return.

Comment: @JesperJuhl together with iostream.h? Good luck.

Comment: @n.m. Heh, I didn't notice that. I guess step 1 should be "get a modern compiler". I'm too used to assuming C++17 (or *at least* C++14).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return at the end of your function. If `size` is not 0 then the behaviour of your function is undefined. Adding the return should make it work:

```
int Occurence(int A[], int size, int n)
{
    static int occur=0;
    if(size == 0)
    {
        int occur2 = (int) occur;
        return occur2;
    }

    else
    {
        if ( n == A[size-1])
            occur++;
        return Occurence(A, size-1, n);
    }
}
```

Recursion is a very strange way to implement this problem so I assume this is some toy example to demonstrate how recursion works. Even if this is the case you really shouldn't be using a static variable in your implementation. Just make each call return the current sum instead:

```
int Occurence(int A[], int size, int n)
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (n == A[size-1] ? 1 : 0) + Occurence(A, size-1, n);
    }
}
```

This version will return the correct result when called multiple times whereas your original would add to the previous count each time.

In real code simply do:

```
#include <algorithm>

int Occurence(int A[], int size, int n)
{
    return std::count(A, A+size, n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some compilation problems in your code. First of all, in C++, the standard library files usually don't have an extension in the filename. So, including `<iostream.h>` is wrong. You should include `<iostream>`.

Other problem with your code is that you are using `cout` and `cin` without specifying their namespaces. So, instead of using `cout` and `cin` directly, use `std::cout` and `std::cin` or declare `use namespace std` after your includes.

EDIT: as Thomas Matthews pointed out, prefer using `std::cout` and `std::cin` over `using namespace std`.

Comment: " in C++, the standard library files don't have an extension in the filenam" - weeel, sometimes that's not true. Believe it or not, some people are still using pre-c++98 compilets/libraries like Turbo C++ and similar. Yeah, it's sad.

Comment: Prefer `using std::cout; using std::cin;` rather than `using namespace std;`.  The latter brings in *all* the `std` namespace symbols.